# Sqlite Column Determination Error

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite, jdbc, jcombobox

I'm trying to get selection from J combo Box and use that to find table from the data base. But instead an error comes up:

[image: The thing that shows]

My codes it:

```
JButton btnGo = new JButton("Go!");
    btnGo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Connection conni = null;
            ResultSet rs=null;
            PreparedStatement pst=null;
            try{
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                conni  = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite://C://Users//Asus//Dropbox//TireShop.sqlite");
                String x = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String sql="select * from " + x;


                pst=conni.prepareStatement(sql);
                rs=pst.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()){
                    String name = rs.getString("Namet");

                    nameofguy.setText(rs.getString(name));
                }

            }catch(Exception i){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, i);

            }
```

I'm searching for table.. but it says cannot find column.

Comment: is there a  column `ayyan`  in your db?  `rs.getString(name)` ??

Comment: Are you trying to check if the table `x` exists in your database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem

```
while(rs.next()){
   String name = rs.getString("Namet");
   //rs.getString returns Ayaan. So value of name is "Ayaan"
   nameofguy.setText(rs.getString(name));
   // Youre trying to get the value corresponding to the column Ayaan here
   //This is why the exception is thrown as there is no column called Ayaan
   }
```

Instead do

```
while(rs.next()){
   String name = rs.getString("Namet");
   nameofguy.setText(name);
   }
```

Comment: Silly mistakes all the time haha. Sorry about that! And thank you very much, I was actually following a tutorial so the application was unknown to me.